# Trying to plot createTreeView and get the Error in tools:::httpdPort > 0L

Tags: r, decision-tree, revolution-r

Recently, I started using R Revolution, and I tried to run a example code to visualize a decision tree.

I ran the code:

```
data("kyphosis", package="rpart") 
kyphTree <- rxDTree(Kyphosis ~ Age + Start + Number, data = kyphosis, cp=0.01) 
library(RevoTreeView)
plot(createTreeView(kyphTree))
```

And got the error:

```
Error in tools:::httpdPort > 0L : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I searched about this error, I'm using the R 3.2.2 and already updated my Rstudio.

Someone could help me?

Tks,

Comment: Where does the error occur? It is not clear from your question. It is highly unlikely that rstudio has anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to RStudio.  It appears to be a bug in the plot function for `revoTreeView`. The error shows that a comparison is being made with `tools:::httpdPort` (first few lines of the `plot.revoTreeView` function).  This is a function, not a number.  Please submit through your Microsoft support channels.

Comment: I got in touch with a Microsoft representative and it really is a bug in the package and it should be fixed in the next realease.  Tks